# ValueError at /Add invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'O'

Tags: python, django

This many to many field "location" saves into the database but the webpage returns this error.

> "ValueError at /Add
>
> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'O'"

**models.py**

```
INSIDEOUTSIDE = (
    ('In','Inside'),
    ('Out', 'Outside'),
)

class location1(models.Model):
    locate = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=INSIDEOUTSIDE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.locate

class Reservation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=22)
    psize = models.IntegerField('Party Size')
    Date = models.DateField()
    Time = models.Tienter code heremeField()
    location = models.ManyToManyField(location1, choices= INSIDEOUTSIDE)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ReservationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ('name', 'psize', 'Date', 'Time', 'location')
        widgets = {'Date': SelectDateWidget(),}
```

**views.py**

```
def add(request):
    form = ReservationsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('Add')
    else:
        form = ReservationsForm()
    return render(request,'app/Add.html',{'form': form})
```

Comment: Did you enter `O` (capital o) instead of a zero?

Comment: No, I want to create a drop down menu with two choices. Inside and outside. When I tried to do this using the many to many field in models.py, the data gets posted to the database, but I get this error. Is there a better way to create a drop down menu from models.py?